# Как сделать такую сетку?

Tags: css

https://codepen.io/manabox/pen/pPvbKZ
можно ли сделать такую сетку без использования `display: grid`?
свойство `grid` вроде ещё плохо поддерживается браузерами

**P.Ss**

https://jsfiddle.net/23eqp7mv/

```css
.grid {
  text-align:center;
  width: 330px;
}
.item {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.item2, .item5 {
  height: 150px;
}
.item7 {
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item item2"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item item5"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item item7"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Инлайнами, флоатами))

Comment: @entithat, можете показать пример? что-то у меня не получается

Comment: https://codepen.io/shayhowe/pen/utfmw, там просто надо будет width менять

Comment: @Сергей Самохвалов, посмотрите внимательно мой пример выше, в вашем примере не то, что нужно

Comment: Я что-то не понял на какой пример выше смотреть. Grid в принципе можно уже использовать, только ie <= 11 не поддерживает, но на них все уже забили

Comment: это то, что вам нужно, там просто width надо поменять, либо можете использовать bootstrap

Comment: @Artem Gorlachev, https://codepen.io/manabox/pen/pPvbKZ сможете такое сделать без использования grid?

Comment: @Сергей Самохвалов, это не то

Comment: @word, как написал Сергей, можно сделать и это пожалуй единственный вариант без grid. Но собьется порядок дивов, и может еще какие-то резиновые части (касательно высоты например). Можно еще display table попробовать. Но на вашем месте я все-же использовал бы grid и просто подогнал бы (кое как) под оставшиеся 3% браузеров

Comment: я так понял на css без использования grid такое нельзя сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Есть решение на флоатах, но не резина:

```css
html, body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
body{
    width:400px;
    height:300px;
}
.puzzle{
    width:300px;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding-top:5px;
}
.puzzle div{
    margin-right:5px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
}
.block1{
    float:left;
    width:70px;
    height:220px;
    background:#3498DB;
}
.block2{
    float:right;
    width:220px;
    height:70px;
    background:#3498DB;
}
.block3{
    height:70px;
    width:70px;
    background:#8e44ad;
}
.block4{
    float:left;
    width:70px;
    height:145px;
    background:#e74c3c;
}
.block5{
    float:right;
    width:70px;
    height:145px;
    background:#e74c3c;
}
.block6{
    float:right;
    width:70px;
    height:70px;
    background:#f1c40f;
}
.block7{
    float:right;
    width:145px;
    height:70px;
    background:#2ECC71;
}
.block8{
    float:left;
    width:145px;
    height:70px;
    background:#2ECC71;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
       <title>Испытание: паззл на флоатах</title>
       <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="puzzle">
 
            
            <div class="block5">5  float:right</div>
               <div class="block7">7 float:right</div>
            <div class="block3">3</div>
           
            
           
         
            
            
         
            
            <div class="block6">6  float:right</div>
            
            
            
         <div class="block1">1 float:left</div>
          <div class="block4">4 float:left</div>
             <div class="block8">8 float:left</div>
            <div class="block2">2  float:right</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: дочерние элементы должны идти списком т.е. .grid > .item*10, без вложенных элементов

Comment: Тогда есть плагин jQuery https://masonry.desandro.com/